# Parametrization of an ellipse

Tags: calculus, parametrization

I'm trying to find the parametrization of the intersection of a sphere and a plane:

\begin{cases} x^2+y^2+z^2=1 \\ x+z=0 \end{cases}

And I end up getting $2x^2+y^2=1$, but I cant't think of a way to write that in the form of $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$, so I can then parametrize the equation.

Comment: I would have thought the intersection of a sphere and a plane might be a circle, while $2x^2+y^2=1$ would be an elliptical cylinder, which includes the circle but many more points too.  Instead I would have thought the intersection might be $(t,\pm\sqrt{1-2t^2},-t)$ with $-\sqrt{\frac12} \le t \le \sqrt{\frac12}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $$2x^2+y^2=1$$
$$\frac{x^2}{\frac{1}{2}}+y^2=1$$
$$\frac{x^2}{(\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}})^2}+\frac{y^2}{1^2}=1$$

Comment: Is this not correct: $$\left(\sqrt{\frac12}cos t, \sqrt{\frac12}sin t, -\sqrt{\frac12} cost\right), \,\,\,\,0\leq t\leq 2\pi$$